# Query time BIG difference between MSSMS and Windows client

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, azure, t-sql

I have developed a WPF client that uses a Azure SQL database to query for invoices on shipments.

The customer have been complaining on long loadtimes for the Shipment list and i have found that for each Shipment the application queries Azure SQL database for invoices on the shipment and that is what takes time.

The queries are made in a foreach loop on each shipment and there is no other way to do it since shipments are loaded from a webservice by filtering in the client.
The invoice table does not have the columns to use the filter.

So to test this I did the folowing:

1. Created a TSQL script that runs Dynamic sql on 100 shipments to get the invoice and executed it in SQL Server management studio.
   Dynamic SQL is executed for each of the 100 shipments.
   I logged the time before the dynamic sql execution and after the
   dynamic sql exeutionExecutiontime for each shipment is 0 milliseconds, which fast enough.
2. Created a Console application in C# that collects 100 shipments from Azure
   stores them in a List and the run a query to get the invoice in a foreachloop on the List. Executiontime for each shipment varies between 43 and 58 milliseconds, which is way to long.
3. To benchmark i created the Invoice table on one of our own SQL servers in our network, copied the data from Azure SQLdatabase and ran the console application.
   Executiontime for each shipment varies between 0 and 15 milliseconds, which is fast enough.

   So my question is how can there be such a dramatic difference between running 100 queries in a loop in Microsoft SQLServer management studio VS a Console application? Does MSSMS have a magic connection?

Samplecode:

```
//Console application

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;

    using System.IO;

    namespace ConsoleApp8
    {
        class Program
        {
            public struct res
            {
                public string ShipmentId;
                public DateTime St;
                public DateTime Sl;
                public double Exectimems;

                public res(string shipmentid, DateTime st)
                {
                    ShipmentId = shipmentid;
                    St = st;
                    Sl = new DateTime();
                    Exectimems = 0;
                }
            }


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                //string connstr = "Data Source=LocalNetWorkSQLServer;Initial Catalog=Dummy;User ID=sa;Password=somepassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
                string connstr = "Server = tcp:Server.database.windows.net;Database=Dummy;User ID =Username@Server;Password=somepassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
                List<string> Shipments = new List<string>();
                List<res> results = new List<res>();

                SqlConnectionStringBuilder scb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connstr);
                //Get all shipments to find invoices on and put them in a list.
                string sql = "Select top 100 ShipmentId"
                + " From("
                + " Select distinct shipmentid"
                + " From TKL_Invoices With(readuncommitted)"
                + " Where OfficeId = 'swe') x";


                using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    cnn.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            Shipments.Add(rd["ShipmentId"].ToString());
                        }

                    }
                    cnn.Close();
                }


                //Get first invoice on each shipment
                sql = "TKL_GetSavedInvoices";
                using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    cnn.Open();

                    foreach (string Shipment in Shipments)
                    {
                        res r = new res(Shipment, DateTime.Now);

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipmentId", Shipment);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeId", "swe");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dbg", "1");

                            string invoice = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                            r.Sl = DateTime.Now;
                            TimeSpan timeDiff = r.St - r.Sl;
                            r.Exectimems = timeDiff.TotalMilliseconds;

                            results.Add(r);

                            Console.WriteLine(Shipment, r.Exectimems.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    cnn.Close();
                }


                //Log result to file
                string prefix = "NetWorkSQLServer";
                if (scb.DataSource.ToLower().Contains("tcp:"))
                    prefix = "Azure";

                string filename = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "WPF_Client_" + prefix + "_QueryResult_" + scb.DataSource.Replace(':','_') + "." + scb.InitialCatalog + ".csv"); 
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                    File.Delete(filename);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("ShipmentId;TimeBeforeQyery;TimeAfterQyery;QueryTimeMilliseconds");
               foreach (res r in results)
                {
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
                        .Append(r.ShipmentId).Append(";")
                        .Append(r.St.ToLongTimeString()).Append(";")
                        .Append(r.Sl.ToLongTimeString()).Append(";")
                        .Append(r.Exectimems.ToString()).Append(";");
                }

                File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("Done");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

SQL database table:

```
    /****** Object:  Index [ix_TKL_Invoices001]    Script Date: 2018-06-21 15:12:43 ******/
    DROP INDEX [ix_TKL_Invoices001] ON [dbo].[Tkl_Invoices]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tkl_Invoices]    Script Date: 2018-06-21 15:12:43 ******/
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Tkl_Invoices]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tkl_Invoices]    Script Date: 2018-06-21 15:12:43 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tkl_Invoices](
        [ShipmentId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [OfficeId] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [InvoiceNo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Tkl_Invoices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ShipmentId] ASC,
        [InvoiceNo] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO

    /****** Object:  Index [ix_TKL_Invoices001]    Script Date: 2018-06-21 15:12:43 ******/
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_TKL_Invoices001] ON [dbo].[Tkl_Invoices]
    (
        [OfficeId] ASC,
        [ShipmentId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

--Data for the table
Insert into Tkl_Invoices(ShipmentId, OfficeId, InvoiceNo)
Select '1511546743', 'SWE', '250279'
Union Select '1512550199', 'SWE', '1111111'
Union Select '1512554318', 'SWE', '250249'
Union Select '1601561108', 'SWE', '250279'
Union Select '1602561957', 'SWE', '249700'
Union Select '1602562876', 'SWE', '250582'
Union Select '1602566412', 'SWE', '250577'
Union Select '1602567219', 'SWE', '249699'
Union Select '1602567387', 'SWE', '250577'
Union Select '1603568831', 'SWE', '250577'
Union Select '1603569044', 'SWE', '250326'
Union Select '1603569143', 'SWE', '249846'
Union Select '1603569720', 'SWE', '249994'
Union Select '1603570257', 'SWE', '250279'
Union Select '1603570259', 'SWE', '250582'
Union Select '1603570940', 'SWE', '1234'
Union Select '1603572374', 'SWE', '250118'
Union Select '1603572376', 'SWE', '250200'
Union Select '1603572378', 'SWE', '250034'
Union Select '1603572450', 'SWE', '249923'
Union Select '1603572450', 'SWE', '250262'
Union Select '1603572601', 'SWE', '249927'
Union Select '1603572603', 'SWE', '250577'
Union Select '1603573496', 'SWE', '249701'
Union Select '1603573826', 'SWE', '249712'
Union Select '1603574012', 'SWE', '250577'
Union Select '1603574022', 'SWE', '250055'
Union Select '1603574184', 'SWE', '249888'
Union Select '1603574193', 'SWE', '249702'
Union Select '1603574195', 'SWE', '250239'
Union Select '1603574417', 'SWE', '249921'
Union Select '1603574610', 'SWE', '1000000'
Union Select '1603574652', 'SWE', '249704'
Union Select '1603574865', 'SWE', '249706'
Union Select '1603574874', 'SWE', '250109'
Union Select '1603575030', 'SWE', '250175'
Union Select '1603575032', 'SWE', '250172'
Union Select '1603575127', 'SWE', '249732'
Union Select '1603575147', 'SWE', '250155'
Union Select '1603575181', 'SWE', '250108'
Union Select '1603575531', 'SWE', '250034'
Union Select '1603575538', 'SWE', '249994'
Union Select '1603575540', 'SWE', '250168'
Union Select '1603575558', 'SWE', '250084'
Union Select '1603575562', 'SWE', '250234'
Union Select '1603575566', 'SWE', '250057'
Union Select '1603575586', 'SWE', '250034'
Union Select '1603575592', 'SWE', '250193'
Union Select '1603575594', 'SWE', '250185'
Union Select '1603575598', 'SWE', '250034'
Union Select '1603575627', 'SWE', '250080'
Union Select '1603575633', 'SWE', '250163'
Union Select '1603575635', 'SWE', '249820'
Union Select '1603575637', 'SWE', '250108'
Union Select '1603575641', 'SWE', '250034'
Union Select '1603575644', 'SWE', '250102'
Union Select '1603575646', 'SWE', '250084'
Union Select '1603575653', 'SWE', '250117'
Union Select '1603575655', 'SWE', '250117'
Union Select '1603575868', 'SWE', '250084'
Union Select '1603575872', 'SWE', '250171'
Union Select '1603575874', 'SWE', '250036'
Union Select '1603575876', 'SWE', '250036'
Union Select '1603575879', 'SWE', '250036'
Union Select '1603575881', 'SWE', '250036'
Union Select '1603575887', 'SWE', '250036'
Union Select '1603575894', 'SWE', '250081'
Union Select '1603575896', 'SWE', '250065'
Union Select '1603575905', 'SWE', '250160'
Union Select '1603575909', 'SWE', '250083'
Union Select '1603575914', 'SWE', '250186'
Union Select '1603575917', 'SWE', '250105'
Union Select '1603575919', 'SWE', '250094'
Union Select '1603575921', 'SWE', '250183'
Union Select '1603575966', 'SWE', '250104'
Union Select '1603575976', 'SWE', '250124'
Union Select '1603575984', 'SWE', '250199'
Union Select '1603575992', 'SWE', '250501'
Union Select '1603575998', 'SWE', '250170'
Union Select '1603576000', 'SWE', '250034'
Union Select '1603576183', 'SWE', '250095'
Union Select '1603576188', 'SWE', '250114'
Union Select '1603576192', 'SWE', '250159'
Union Select '1603576209', 'SWE', '250129'
Union Select '1603576268', 'SWE', '250176'
Union Select '1603576286', 'SWE', '250130'
Union Select '1603576294', 'SWE', '249715'
Union Select '1603576296', 'SWE', '249716'
Union Select '1604576489', 'SWE', '250135'
Union Select '1604576823', 'SWE', '250036'
Union Select '1604576884', 'SWE', '250039'
Union Select '1604576909', 'SWE', '250145'
Union Select '1604576913', 'SWE', '249922'
Union Select '1604576944', 'SWE', '249682'
Union Select '1604577069', 'SWE', '249717'
Union Select '1604577112', 'SWE', '250082'
Union Select '1604577121', 'SWE', '250234'
Union Select '1604577133', 'SWE', '250234'
Union Select '1604577137', 'SWE', '250234'
Union Select '1604577139', 'SWE', '250234'

--SQL Stored procedure to get invoices(@Dbg is to get one invoice only)
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TKL_GetSavedInvoices]    Script Date: 2018-06-21 15:23:51 ******/
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[TKL_GetSavedInvoices]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TKL_GetSavedInvoices]    Script Date: 2018-06-21 15:23:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


CREATE procedure [dbo].[TKL_GetSavedInvoices]
@ShipmentId nvarchar(50)
,@OfficeId  nvarchar(255) = null
,@Dbg smallint = 0
as
begin

declare @InvoiceNo nvarchar(50)

    if Exists(Select 1 From TKL_Invoices with(readuncommitted)
    where   ShipmentId = @ShipmentId
            and OfficeId = isnull(@OfficeId, OfficeId)
            )
    begin
        If(@dbg = 0)
        begin
            select 
            InvoiceNo
            from    TKL_Invoices with(readuncommitted)
            where   ShipmentId = @ShipmentId
                    and OfficeId = isnull(@OfficeId, OfficeId)
            order   by Head desc
            OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN )
        End Else
        begin
            select 
            @InvoiceNo = InvoiceNo
            from    TKL_Invoices with(readuncommitted)
            where   ShipmentId = @ShipmentId
                    and OfficeId = isnull(@OfficeId, OfficeId)
            order   by Head desc
            OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN )

            Select @InvoiceNo as InvoiceNo
        End
  End Else
  begin
    Select 'NA' as InvoiceNo
  End
end
GO
```

Comment: For 1) are you running one script, then another, then another (i.e. 100 separate `Execute`s)? Or are you clicking `Execute` just once?

Comment: Yes 100 executions of the dynamic query to get the invoice.

Comment: Running 100 queries is the problem. Why can't you use a single query instead? I know you said this is using a webservice but I would create a new web method to get all the data instead of calling it 100 times. And be careful using read uncommitted. Especially with things like invoices. It is not a magic go fast button, it some very serious baggage with it. Things like randomly getting duplicate and/or missing rows. And a whole bunch of other "fun" stuff. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Try to add OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN ) to your "If exists" query

Comment: Tested that now and there is no difference.

Comment: As explained there is no way to NOT run 100 queries due to application design.
We support this application but we are not the creators.

The question is not about the 100 Q´s it is why it´s so much faster i Management studion.

Comment: I notice you are using `AddWithValue` which does not specify the data types.  That might cause some parameter sniffing to occur and perhaps the wrong indexes being chosen.  Does it make any difference if you use something like `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipmentId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Shipment;`?  (Be sure to use the correct data type in the call to `Add`)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I’ll test this after midsummer hollidays.

Comment: You have the list of 100.  Why do you need to loop 100 times?

Answer (score 0):

This is wasteful!

```
foreach (string Shipment in Shipments)
{
     res r = new res(Shipment, DateTime.Now);

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
     {
           cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipmentId", Shipment);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeId", "swe");
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dbg", "1");
```

Why are taking the overhead a new command on every loop rather than holding on to the command?

```
public static void SQLLoop()
{
    List<string> shipments = new List<string>();
    string sql = "adsffo;hkjasd";
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("asfd"))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            List<res> results = new List<res>();

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipmentId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficeId", "swe");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dbg", "1");

            foreach (string shipment in shipments)
            {
                res r = new res(shipment, DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters["@ShipmentId"].Value = shipment;

                string invoice = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                r.Sl = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan timeDiff = r.St - r.Sl;
                r.Exectimems = timeDiff.TotalMilliseconds;

                results.Add(r);

                Console.WriteLine(shipment, r.Exectimems.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got a point but that would not explain the difference between C# and MSSMS since i make a new command in TSQL as well. The Q is not to review my code!

Comment: No you do NOT create a command anywhere in the SQL loop.  You create a new select.  Sorry I tried to help.  SQL does not have magic your code is just flawed.

Comment: Ok so I’m missunderstanding dynamic sql  then? I’ll try your tip.

Comment: SOLVED:
Found another solution for this.
since I now the ShipmentIds, I Sort the List, get the MIN and MAX ShipmentId (They are in a fixed format and always numeric) and get all invoices with one query.

I tried this with 100 shipments and it´s super fast.

Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Thanks for a real bad question I answered as written.  You do not show programming or problem solving skills.

Comment: Thanks a lot pap. Next time you see a q from me just ignore it, I`m just to stupid to even ask the question correctly. Or just focus on the question next time.

Comment: You get them all with one query?  You were pretty emphatic that was not an option.  "As explained there is no way to NOT run 100 queries due to application design."

Comment: Ye I know and Im sorry for that. Still that doe not answer the question asked.

Comment: Yes it does you just don't understand and I am OK with that.